# SimpleDateFormat don't parse a string with a date when I use setLenient()

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I don't understand what is going wrong with the code below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy hh:mm:ss");
formatter.setLenient(false);
formatter.parse("04.29.2017 00:55:05");
```

When I try to parse the string with a date I have a `java.text.ParseException`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: That should be `yyyy` if your year is 4 chars long. And why are you making it strict?

Comment: Also, the doc says: "h  Hour in am/pm (1-12) ". 00 is thus not in the valid range. Read the javadoc (and the message and stack trace of the exception).

Comment: I don't want parse wrong date like "33.13.2017 00:55:05". I saw that setLenient(false) can help in this situation.

Comment: Thank you all very much!!! I'm stupid)...

Comment: @Katran1990 Search Stack Overflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of code examples to compare to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hh expects a range of 1 through 12. Change it to HH (0 through 23) if you want it to work with lenient off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `yyyy` format (as 2017 is `yyyy`).

I have also removed `formatter.setLenient(false);` as this is not required.

Like this:

```
public class DateParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = formatter.parse("04.29.2017 00:55:05");

        System.out.println(myDate);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Sat Apr 29 00:55:05 BST 2017